# Question to find the value of P in following question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b$ and $c$ be such that $$a + b + c = 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad P =
\frac{a^2}{2a^2 + bc} + \frac{b^2}{2b^2 + ca} + \frac{c^2}{2c^2 + ab}.$$
How could I find Integral value of $P$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an easier way with little calculations :

Note that :

$$a(a+b+c)=0$$ so $$a^2=-ab-ac$$

Now plug in and factorise:

$$2a^2+bc=a^2+a^2+bc=a^2-ab-ac+bc=(a-b)(a-c)$$ and the others in the same manner .

$$P=\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{b^2}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}=\frac{-(b-c)a^2-(c-a)b^2-(a-b)c^2}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}=\frac{a^2c+b^2a+c^2b-a^2b-b^2c-c^2a}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$

Now it's easy to see that the numerator and denominator are actually the same .

You can see this by expansion or by some factoring :

$$a^2c+b^2a+c^2b-a^2b-b^2c-c^2a=c(a^2-b^2)+ab(b-a)+c^2(b-a)=(b-a)(c^2+ab-ca-cb)=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$

This means that $P=1$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Eliminate  $c$  with $-(a+b)$

$$2a^2+bc=2a^2-b(a+b)=(2a+b)(a-b)$$

$$2b^2+ca=2b^2-(a+b)a=(2b+a)(a-b)$$

$$2c^2+ab=2(a+b)^2+ab=(2a+b)(a+b)$$

Now add by taking LCM of the denominators

Answer (score 0):

$a=0,b=1,c=-1$ can be trivial solution to it seeing by observation. So generalized as $0,k,-k$ can be partial answer.$k$ cant be $0$. But surely you can get some different solutions by solving the equation as it is symmetric. Hope its clear.

Comment: what is trivial solution. Please explain.

Comment: One of the solutions